# asp.net compilation has browser issue

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am compiling asp.net 2.0 code. I have IE 8. When I compile application, it open two browser. One browser is blank and other one show web form after a while.

why it happening?

Comment: Is this actually happening when you start the application (e.g. using F5, or Ctrl-F5)?  Could it be that you have two web sites in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 web projects in the solution and it's starting both of them up.  To avoid this, go to properties on the one you don't want, the **Web** tab, then change the **Start Action** to **Don't open a page.**